# How to surround block of text by noindex tags?

Tags: wordpress, tags, shortcode

I want to overwrite text blocks with noindex tags using short codes:

[image]

Here I add noindex shortcode:

[image]

But when I start the function the block of text just disappears:

[image]

My function and result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. 
Add it to your functions.php file instead of the one you wrote:

```
function noindex($content = null) 
{
return '<noindex>'.$content.'</noindex>';
}
add_shortcode("noindex", "noindex");
```